# How to enable a Webview Video Download button?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Android How to enable `Webview` video Download button on Android. I want to enable the download video  by clicking the download icon of the `html` video player download button.

[image]

like this above image download button and download the video.

Comment: you have multiple questions: How do I create an overflow menu, How do I add icons to the overflow menu, How do I add a click listener to an item in the overflow menu, How to intercepts videos in WebView , How to download videos within a WebView. Am I right?

Comment: Make sure your HTML `<video>` tag has the attribute `controls`

Comment: @ZUNJAE how did you assume all that from her simple question regarding the "download" button?

Comment: I am asking for confirmation. It's only normal that I assumed this cause I'm unsure myself. Do you not understand the concept of asking questions to other people?

Comment: @MehdiB.<video> tag is not in my control.

Comment: @ZUNJAE Please solution??

Comment: @MehdiB. Solution Please??

Comment: @SoniyaJoshi sorry, I don't know of a way to achieve that if you don't have access to the HTML or the url